# Questions about driver scripted expression

Tags: scripting, drivers

At the moment driver scripted expression is giving me a hard time and hopefully someone can help to figure out how does it work.

[image]

[image]

Here are the questions.

1. How can this expression be written in the text editor (python) instead of the small textarea?
2. How can another if-else statement (`var if (var<4.461+var_neg) else (4.461+var_neg)`) be added to the first one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi.  [Using the Driver Namespacel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#driver-namespace)

Comment: Like the error message says, `var_pos` is not defined.  Perhaps the driver method needs to be `def test(var, var_pos):`

Comment: thanks batFINGER but the var_pos is added to the driver variables and if i use the text directly in the driver panel everything works

Comment: To reiterate:, In the [Image You Posted in Comment](http://imgur.com/e7RFGi8) (since deleted) the driver expression is failing because `var_pos` is not defined. (line 6 in test yada, yada)

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need as separate posts.